# MySQL calculate date diff if greater than 35 days

Tags: mysql, datediff

how to calculate datediff between two dates if difference is greater than 35 days?

This is my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(IF('2017-08-01 10:00:00' < NOW(), '-', ''), FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), '2017-08-01 10:00:00')) / 24), ' days ',
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),'2017-08-01 10:00:00')), 24), ' hours ', MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),'2017-08-01 10:00:00')), ' minutes') AS TimeLeft
```

But it shows wrong calculation.

```
+------------------------------+
| TimeLeft                     |
+------------------------------+
| -34 days 22 hours 59 minutes |
+------------------------------+
```

It should be at least 100 day difference.

Comment: What does "wrong calculation" exactly mean?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Wrong calculation means that in my case i get around 34 days and it should be about 100 day difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff says:

> The result returned by TIMEDIFF() is limited to the range allowed for TIME values.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html says:

> TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.

Then we realize that

```
FLOOR(838 hours / 24 hours) = 34
```

Here's an alternative that works (at least until 2038):

```
mysql> select concat(
  ceil(tdiff/24/60/60), ' days, ',
  floor(mod(abs(tdiff)/60/60, 24)), ' hours, ',
  floor(mod(abs(tdiff)/60, 60)), ' minutes') as t
from (select unix_timestamp('2017-08-01 10:00:00') - unix_timestamp(now()) as tdiff) as t;
+---------------------------------+
| t                               |
+---------------------------------+
| -100 days, 13 hours, 10 minutes |
+---------------------------------+
```

Here's another idea:

```
mysql> select to_days('1970-01-01')-to_days(td) as days, time(td) as hhmmss
 from (select from_unixtime(abs(unix_timestamp('2017-08-01 10:00:00') - unix_timestamp(now()))); 
+------+----------+
| days | hhmmss   |
+------+----------+
| -100 | 13:18:12 |
+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

timediff has a limitation of max. 838:59:59 or about 35 days that you have found out. For queries with greater differences, use "TIMESTAMPDIFF" instead.

Example:
SELECT id, tstamp, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, tstamp, '2037-09-07 07:59:59') FROM `work`;